# Bayesian parameter estimation homework problem

Tags: self-study, pattern-recognition

For BPE approach,for p($\theta$)~U(0,1) show that

p(x|D)=  $1/n+2[(x+ \sum_{k=1}^n(x_k)!)$ $ (n+1-x-$($\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k)$!]$/$[$(\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k))$! $(n-\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k))$!]

I have tried using the following equation

p(x|D)= $\int p(x|\mu)p(\mu|D)d\mu$

I have substituted for the 2 terms but unable to reach the required solution

Comment: It would help to explain your notation: what is $D$?  What is $x$?  How (if at all) is $x$ related to the $x_k$?  How are these $x$'s related to $D$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Sample set $\D={x_1,..,x_n}$ , p(x|D) -> Probability density and x is the feature

Comment: Isn't it cheating to ask other people to solve your homework problem?

Comment: Not to solve it. just want a couple of hints coz i'm stuck.

Comment: Do you have functional forms for p(x|μ)p(μ|D)? What is the data likelihood you are to use?